# Testing AppServer/Database Availability Remotely in Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We have Progress appservers (OE 10.0B05) running on AIX UNIX and I want write some code to check if they are up and running. The code to check the appserver would be run from a WIN2008 server. I can pull up Progress Explorer on the WIN2008 server to check the status of the appservers, but I need to write some code that can check their status programatically.

Is there any way to programatically check whether my AIX UNIX Progress appserver is up and running from a remote WIN2008 server?

Comment: Do you want to know if the aix server is running?  Or if a specific Progress App Server on that AIX server is running?  And you mention db availability in the title but not in the question -- do you need to know something about the db too?

Comment: I am not the OP, but I'd be interested in being able to query the status of the appserver, like number of active clients, requests being served, requests in the queue, avg. waiting time etc. ... would this be doable?

Comment: @TomBascom - I want to know if a specific Progress App Server on the AIX system is up and running. Do you have any other ideas besides Tim's suggestion to open a socket connection? I was hoping that Progress has some type of tool that can be instantiated programmatically to return app server status information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get app server status information you can use "asbman".

To get it remotely you would need some means to invoke a remote process and return a value.  I'm a unix guy so I usually use "ssh" for that sort of thing.

There are Windows versions of SSH (look at the PuTTY suite for a really good free option). If you set it up to use pre-shared keys or an "agent" there are no messy login prompts to get in the way.  Something like (untested):

plink -i sshkey.ppk user@server.name "asbman -name appServer -query"

"asbman" also supports -host and -port parameters if you happen to have it running on the windows box that you want to make the inquiry from.

Comment: Yup, I know about "asbman", I hoped that appservers offered JMX support or something similar, though...

Comment: @pmartin Here is a concise introduction to asbman: http://cronostech.wordpress.com/2011/04/27/checking-application-servers-state/ - you probably have to build something in Perl, Python or whatever to launch it on request, and parse the information you want to return to the caller.

Comment: The original post refers to 10.05B -- which seems like it might be a typo.  If it is actually somewhere in the 10.0 series (maybe 10.0B5?) then there is very little chance.  If it is actually 10.2B05 then /maybe/ there is something -- PSC did put support for Actional "interceptors" into app servers recently (I'm not sure if 10.2B made the cut or if it is an OE11 thing).  I haven't looked into the details at all but that /might/ be related to something like JMX.  So you might want to pursue that if you are on 10.2B or better.

Comment: @TomBascom I fixed the version info in the post. It should have read 10.0B05.

Comment: @TomBascom: where can I find more about these Actional interceptors?

Comment: @TomBascom - asbman would work great! I have this available on the WIN2008 server and I can call this programatically. My only problem is that asbman requires a password when connecting to remote hosts and I don't see a way that I can pass that in a command line argument. Any ideas (besides using SSH) on how to get around this?

Comment: @pmartin - regarding the password:  maybe you can redirect it from a file?  (I haven't tried but that sometimes works with other situations).

Comment: @p.marino There should be something on Progress.com -- searching "actional interceptor for openedge" turns up a bunch of stuff.  This http://blogs.progress.com/openedge/2009/07/openedge-102b-beta.html indicates that 10.2B would be the minimum release.

Comment: @pmartin - 10.0B05 is awfully old...  quite aside from the issue at hand you ought to be looking at an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small program that can open a socket connection, that would do it. If the program can open a socket, you can be reasonably confident the appserver is running.

You -might- be able to use the ABL SOCKET functionality to do this. Failing that, any other program which can open a socket on a remote machine and then close it will work.b